# Oracle unpivot of table data

Tags: oracle

Given the table `PerformerTours` with the columns:

```
FirstName, LastName, Date_1, City_1, State_1, Date_2, City_2, State_2, Date_3, City_3, State_3, Date_4, City_4, State_4
```

and the data

```
Donna, Summers, 01/01/20, Atlanta, Georgia
James, Taylor, 02/04/20, Miami, Florida, 04/11/20, Seattle, Washington
Bob, Dylan, 01/11/20, Buffalo, New York, 09/24/20, Nashville, Tennessee, 10/22/20, Chicago, Illinois, 12/12/20, Denver, Colorado
Kenny, Rankin, 06/30/20, Las Vegas, Nevada, 07/04/20, Boston, Massachusetts, 08/18/20, Cincinnati, Ohio
```

how can I unpivot the data to be as defined below using just Oracle SQL:

```
Donna, Summers, 01/01/20, Atlanta, Georgia
James, Taylor, 02/04/20, Miami, Florida
James, Taylor, 04/11/20, Seattle, Washington
Bob, Dylan, 01/11/20, Buffalo, New York 
Bob, Dylan, 09/24/20, Nashville, Tennessee
Bob, Dylan, 10/22/20, Chicago, Illinois
Bob, Dylan, 12/12/20, Denver, Colorado
Kenny, Rankin, 06/30/20, Las Vegas, Nevada
Kenny, Rankin, 07/04/20, Boston, Massachusetts
Kenny, Rankin, 08/18/20, Cincinnati, Ohio
```

Comment: Who's Bob Dyan?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - American singer-songwriter most popular in the 1960's.  Then again, I have a neighbor down the street named Bod Dylan -- could be him I'm referring to.

Comment: Please tell me that you're doing this as a /one-off exercise/ to get your data into the properly *Normalised* form that you intended to work with in future! 

This repetition of fields within a records breaks even /First/ Normal Form and is a /nightmare/ to work with.

Comment: @PhillW. Just an exercise in using and learning to pivot and unpivot data.

Comment: @tale852150 I never heard of any 60's artist named "Bob Dyan". I do have an album by **Bob Dylan** though.

Comment: Typo — should be Bob Dylan...

Comment: Enfin. Took you a while.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille  Lol - I had a corrupted index in my memory database... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Date, City, State FROM performertours
  UNPIVOT Exclude nulls (
    (date,city,state)
    FOR tour    IN (
      (Date_1, City_1, State_1) AS 'T1',
      (Date_2, City_2, State_2) AS 'T2', 
      (Date_3, City_3, State_3) AS 'T3',
      (Date_4, City_4, State_4) AS 'T4'
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select FirstName, LastName, Date_1 as date, City_1 as city, State_1 as state
  From performertours
Union all
Select FirstName, LastName, Date_2, City_2, State_2
  From performertours where date_2 is not null
Union all
Select FirstName, LastName, Date_3, City_3, State_3
  From performertours where date_3 is not null
Union all
Select FirstName, LastName, Date_4, City_4, State_4
  From performertours where date_4 is not null
```

Comment: work great!  Do you know of any way to do this using the UNPIVOT clause?

Comment: No, I used to insist on a normalized database design.